# Samba - File size limit exceeded

Tags: samba, raspberrypi

I am trying to copy 'large' file (about 1GB) from my Windows PC to the Raspberry PI 3 samba server.
It is OK when I try to copy about 350MB files but with larger files I'm still having this error

```
File size limit exceeded
```

I was searching for any solution on the web but without success...

This is how I mount a disk (connected through USB)

```
/dev/sda2 /mnt/hdd ntfs-3g defaults,noatime,nofail,umask=000 $
```

And here is my smb.conf file (part of it)

```
[pi_share]
comment = Pi_hdd
path = /mnt/hdd
read only = no
```

And [whole file](http://pastebin.com/raw/5D2tT1nG)

Could you help me with this?